# Guava EventBus : where to put it in GUI application?

Tags: java, guava

Is there a best place to put a [guava EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) in a GUI application ? Is there in the Model, the View, or the Controler ? Or three EventBus in the three levels ? Or only two of them ?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you have a solution in search of a problem. Are you using EventBus because you think it's cool, or because there is a need it is addressing?

Comment: I use EventBus because it's cool, AND because there is a need :-) My Swing GUI is not very stable.If I use the swing listener event style, refactoring is difficult.  Also, the link between model and vue is tedious. I think (I hope) it's more easy with a event bus concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event bus design pattern is often used in Swing applications (as mentioned [in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350058/142983)).

Guava's EventBus is just another implementation of the design pattern, with some cool tricks to simplify event handling (such as using annotations). But the goal of using the design pattern stays the same.

If I were you, I'd look into how the event bus pattern is usually used in rich client applications (on SO / Google), while using the Guava EventBus to simplify your code.

The EventBus should IMO be a singleton (ideally injected through Google Guice or some other DI framework).

I'm not a Swing dev, but I've done GWT development. A while ago, there was a big push toward the MVP / EventBus architecture for GWT applications. It might be work looking into it, to see if you could apply the same ideas to your Swing app.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at this experience someone recently had.

http://stupidgwttricks.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/using-guavas-eventbus-to-decouple-components-of-a-swing-application/

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, it's a singleton eventbus, at application level, to send event from Vue to Controler. Interesting.

Comment: Correct, but I would say that it would be a good separation to have an event bus for the GUI only. If you have other layers, just use other(s) buses for these layers.